# Xcode: Autocreate Schemes Now - not working

Tags: xcode

I've checked out an old project with Xcode and Schemes is empty.

However, if I click on `Manage Schemes` and `Autocreate Schemes Now` nothing happens.
Fwiw, I'm running Xcode Version 5.0.2 (5A3005).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you have another scheme pointing to the target, Xcode won't create another scheme for that target.  Usually this is a Xcode test module already pointing to a target.